# What is the function/meaning of "Так, < Name >"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Woman: Если это касается XXX, я буду через минуту.
>
> Man: **Так**, Вероника. (This is an urgent matter that requires your immediate attention.)

The following two meanings came to mind, but neither seems to fit the bill here.

> "**so**" in the sense of "therefore"
>
> {or}: "**well**" in the sense of "ну"

Comment: most likely it means objection but without greater context it's hard to tell for sure

Answer (score 7):

The phrase **"Так, < Name >"** could either express an agreement, or call for attention with a following order.

**Agreement / Acknowledgement:**
The phrase ends the statement.

> ... Так, Вероника. / *Yes, Veronica. / Indeed, Veronica.*

**An order:**
The phrase is followed by the details of the order.

> Так, Вероника, срочно на диету. / *Listen Veronica, start dieting ASAP.*
>
> Так, Холмогоров, зовите наряд... / *Listen Kholmogorov, call a police patrol...*

Additionally, the same phrase as a question is a **request for clarification/confirmation:**

> — Так, Вармишев? / *Is it so Varmishev?*
>
> — Так. / *Yes.*

Comment: or perhaps, "Now, Veronika,...". "So,..." and "Well,..." can fit to. Context-depending.

Comment: As an agreement it would not be typical for modern Russian. In western Slavic languages, like Polish, West-Ukrainian, "так" means "yes" literally. But in Russian it changed its meaning to "so".

Answer (score 6):

I'd translate this as

> Listen, Veronika.

or

> Look, Veronika.